# Typescript: Check if object keys and values fits to current class properties

Tags: typescript, types

I need to check if object keys and values fits to current class properties.
I have class instance and the changes in separate object then I call Object.assign to modify properties. Is there any way how to check if the object key and values are valid for certain class?

```
class MyClass {
  icon = 'home'
  size = 12
  color = 'blue'
}

var instance = new MyClass()

var changeProperties: MyClass = { size: 10 }
// throws Property 'icon' is missing in type { size: number; }

Object.assign(instance, changeProperties)
```

Now got errors for not defined properties (property icon is missing).

I have tried `var changeProperties: { [string: keyof MyClass]: any } = { size: true }` with no success.

Note: I can't change the class itself (eg. make class properties optional).

Comment: Do you want to use the check so that you know what type to instantiate?

Comment: I need autocomplete and typecheck for changeProperties var, I have updated the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer in lib.es6.d.ts

```
/**
 * Make all properties in T optional
 */
type Partial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
};
```

So the answer is:

```
class MyClass {
  icon = 'home'
  size = 12
  color = 'blue'
}

var instance = new MyClass()

var changeProperties: Partial<MyClass> = { size: 10 }

Object.assign(instance, changeProperties)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can always tell TS that we know more, i.e.

```
// instead of this
var changeProperties: MyClass = { size: 10 }
// we can assure TS that we know more than it..
var changeProperties: MyClass = { size: 10 } as MyClass
```

That is assertion - a statement for TS - instructing it that the passed object is really what it should be

Comment: is there any other way than type assertion?

Comment: Well, I'd say.. we either want the **type safety** *(and screaming TS compiler is informing that incomplete object is not complete)* or we want to silence it... because we know it better. For second scenario - there is no other way. For first, we can just to create another type, which is not so restrictive (`interface IHaveSize { size: number}` ). A to je čistá pravda ač nemilá ;)

Comment: Well actually you can do that via Partial type see me aswer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but maybe something like that

```
class MyClass {
   icon = 'home'
   size = 12
   color = 'blue'
}

//just copied from your code, I don't know the purpose of it
var instance = new MyClass()

var changeProperties: MyClass = new MyClass();
var properties = { size: 10, hello: 'test'};

for(const property of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(properties)) {

   if(instance.hasOwnProperty(property) && typeof instance[property] === typeof properties[property]) {

       instance[property] = properties[property];
   }
}
```

Maybe there is a better solution but that's how I solved something similar.

if you look at `instance` after the loop you will see that `hello` has been ignored and is not assigned.
the same happens if you change `size` in `properties` to a string.
`instance.size` will then still be 12.

hope it helps.

See resources:

- [Object.getPropertyNames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)
- [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

It will only work wit IE9+

P.S. I only tested and used it with simple types like string, numbers etc.

Comment: yea that solution for runtime check, is there any way to do it in typescript before execution?

Comment: If I remember correctly I haven't found a way to do it otherwise (and I'm not sure if it is even possible), but would be interested if there is a solution.